# Show that two vector spaces are isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

> Let $M$ be a set and above a field $\mathbb{K}$ let $\mathcal{L}(M, \mathbb{K})$ be a vector space of all mappings from $M \to K$.
>
> Show that if there is a bijective function $h: M \to N$ then $\mathcal{L}(M, \mathbb{K})$ and $\mathcal{L}(N, \mathbb{K})$ are isomophic.

My idea was since $h$ is bijective and one can easily find a bijective function $g: \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{K}$ that there exists $\phi: \mathcal{L}(M, \mathbb{K}) \to \mathcal{L}(N, \mathbb{K})$ that is bijective aswell. Next I need to show that $\phi$ is linear. Naively I would say

$$
\phi(f+g) = f + g = \phi(f) + \phi(g), \ f,g \in \mathcal{L}(M, \mathbb{K})
$$
and
$$
\phi(\alpha f) = \alpha \cdot f = \alpha  \cdot \phi(f)
$$

Comment: You need to explicitly define $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your argument. I don't see why you want to define $g$ and why are you writing $\phi(f) = f$.

Let $V=\mathcal{L}(M,\mathbb{K})$, $W=\mathcal{L}(N,\mathbb{K})$.

I think the easiest thing to do is to use composition with $h$ to pass from $W$ to $V$. If $w:N\to\mathbb{K}$, then $w\circ h:M\to \mathbb{K}$, so you can define a mapping $H:W\to V$ as
$$Hw = w\circ h\,.$$

Then the linearity follows clearly and can be verified testing the mappings on an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{K}$.

Explicitly, for each $k\in \mathbb{K}$, for each $w,w'\in W$, for each $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{K}$

$$H(\alpha w+\beta w')(k) = (\alpha w + \beta w')(h(k)) = \alpha w(h(k)) + \beta w'(h(k)) = (\alpha H w + \beta H w')(k)$$

Now you just need to show that $H$ it's invertible. But for any $v\in V$, it's clear that $v = H(v \circ h^{-1})$, so $H$ is surjective. Then you have that $Hw \equiv 0$ implies that $w$ is $0$ on the image of $h$, which is $\mathbb{K}$ itself. So $H$ is injective (since it's linear) and you conclude.

Comment: can you elaborate more on 1) what you mean with $Hw$? $H$ is your mapping from $W \to V$ and $w: N \to \mathbb{K}$ but what exactly is $Hw$? And 2) why exactly does $0 = w \circ h \Leftrightarrow h^{-1}(0) = w \Leftrightarrow 0 = w$ hold true?

Comment: $w$ is a map from $N$ to $\mathbb{K}$, so it's an element of $W$. $H$ is  a map from $W$ to $V$ so $H w$ is an element of $V$, which is a map $M\to\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: $H w\equiv 0$ means that for any $k\in \mathbb{K}$ you have $(w\circ h)(k) = w(h(k)) = 0$. This means that for any $k'$ such that there exists a $k$ such that $h(k) = k'$ you have that $w k' = 0$. This can be restated as: "For every $k'$ in the image of $h$, $w(k') = 0$.". Since $h$ is a bijection, $h$ is surjective, so its image is $\mathbb{K}$. So, if $Hw\equiv 0$, then for every $k'\in\mathbb{K}$ you have $w(k') = 0$, which means $w\equiv 0$.